# Get users filtering Sharepoint search API refinementfilter by month

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, search-api

I need to get all users by refining hire date managed property in this week using SharePoint search APi.

I'm tried lots of ways but not succeeded. Please help me on this.

What will come in refinement filter query for checking with month or week?

Answer (score 0):

There are several KQL keywords you can use to play with date intervals. In your case you can use the following:

1. `HireDate:this week` to check for current week.
2. `HireDate:this month` to check for current month

See this post for all [KQL syntax.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx)

Comment: hi Unnie, thanks for reply. how to use this in REST API query, I tried like **/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&rowlimit=500&selectproperties='PreferredName,HireDate'&refinementfilters='HireDate:"this week"' **and **/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&rowlimit=500&selectproperties='PreferredName,HireDate'&refinementfilters='HireDate:euqals("this week")' but not succeseeded